# install4j Preserving symbolic links within included directories

Tags: install4j

Is it possible for install4j to preserve any symbolic links found within the specified build directories, without having to manually create said links programatically?  My installer has to include a large directory structure of files, but there are a fair number of relative symbolic links within said files.  When I install using the generated installer, all the symbolic links are missing.

Answer (score 0):

As of install4j 7 this is not possible, the file collector does not pick up symbolic links during compilation.

You could tar the distribution directory, add the tar file to the distribution tree and use a "Extract a TAR file" action on the "Installation" screen of your installer, then a "Delete files and directories" action to delete the installed tar file.